# Is the asymptotic growth rate of the product of divisor function up to $n$ known?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, divisor-counting-function

Let $\tau(k)$ be the number of divisors of the positive integer $k.$

How does $f(n)\stackrel{\triangle}{=}\prod_{k\leq n} \tau(k)$ or a reasonable function of it,such as $\log f(n)$ or $f(n)^{1/n}$ grow with increasing $n$? Any references, comments appreciated.

Comment: It's tabulated at https://oeis.org/A066843 but with no information on growth rate.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson,Thanks. I'd like to migrate to Mathoverflow to see if it gets more traction. I have added some numerical data.

Comment: [MathOverflow version](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/222976/what-is-the-asymptotic-growth-rate-of-the-product-of-divisor-function-up-to-n) of this question.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer:** I can see that from the arithmetic geometric mean inequality we have $$\prod_{k\leq n} \tau(k) \leq \left(\frac{\tau(1)+\cdots+\tau(n)}{n} \right)^n \approx (\log n+2\gamma-1+O(n^{-1/2}))^n \approx (\log n)^n \left(1+\frac{(2\gamma-1) n}{\log n}\right)$$ due to the well known asymptotic $$\tau(1)+\cdots+\tau(n)\approx n \log n +(2\gamma-1)n+O(\sqrt{n}).$$

The issue is, is there a tighter upper bound?

Here is a logarithmic plot of the upper bound approximation above and the actual product

[image: upper bound and product in log scale]

Here is a plain plot of the ratio of the upper bound to the product, where the variability of the product with respect to the smooth upper bound is visible

[image]